# Is it possible to copy a variable to the Shift+Insert clipboard from the command line?

Tags: command-line, bash, clipboard, xclip

When I create scripts, I use the `xclip` command to copy a variable to the clipboard, so I can paste it using `CTRL+V` or automate my script to paste it with `xdotool`. The command that I use to copy a variable to the clipboard is this one:

```
echo -n "$clipboard" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

It works fine for pasting with `CTRL+V`... However, many times I want to paste things on a terminal window and only `Shift+Insert` works for that. For some reason `xclip` doesn't copy variables to the clipboard that `Shift+Insert` uses, it only happens when I copy some text manually with `CTRL+C`. **Does anyone know if there's a way of programmatically copying a variable to the same clipboard that Shift+Insert uses?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Shift+Insert` uses the `XA_PRIMARY` selection. So:

```
echo -n "$clipboard" | xclip -selection primary
```

or just

```
echo -n "$clipboard" | xclip
```

(since `XA_PRIMARY` is the default).

Comment: or, to save the `echo` call and the pipe, just: `<<<"$clipboard" xclip`